# What website is this?

Tags: online-chess

Someone sent me a screenshot of a chess website with detailed analysis. What is this website? Where does it come from? It doesn't look like lichess to me, I have no idea.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The board here looks similar: http://analysis.sesse.net

Comment: The board itself seems to be from http://chessboardjs.com which likely is used on many chess sites. Is it possible to reproduce the exact output on analysis.sesse.net ?

Comment: @user1583209: Sesse is someone's private site, now and then he lets it follow some live game (e.g. during the WC match).